# Handle leak when socket is forcibly closed by remote host? (.net)

Tags: .net, sockets, memory-leaks

I have created a simple tcp based "echo protocol" and notice that I suffer from handle leak on the server when the client forcibly closes the connection (sends a reset).

I catch the ConnectionReset and dispose the socket in the same way I do when the socket is closed (socket.Shutdown and socket.close). As anybody encountered such a problem?
The ConnectionReset exception is thrown while I'm doing a socket.Read, if it matters.

Thanks.

Edit: Microsoft's DebugDiag tool suggests those are event handlers created by MSCORLIB. Needless to say that I don't create those directly (but they are created somewhere by the .net library)

Answer (score 1):

Socket.Recieve and Socket.Write are, unfortunately, the only places to detect when the other end closes it's sockets forcibly rather than correctly.

`Socket.Close()` should (according to my intellisense) release the socket handle.

So first make sure `Socket.Close()` is indeed being called. Then check other places for handle leaks, are you using any objects that require disposing that aren't being disposed? Such as opening `FileStream`s?

Comment: It is indeed being called. No file streams, but anyway, I do treat reset sockets as nicely closed sockets. (and I do get the exception while performing Read)

Answer (score -1):

I think you do it right:

Socket.Close should free all managed and unmanaged ressources associated to the socket.

But did you also try to set

```
socket = null;
```

And maybe (after that) use

```
GC.Collect();
```

to manually trigger the garbage collector, is the leak still present after this?

Another idea:
How do you monitor the handle leak? The OS might keep a closed TCP connection in memory for a long time (minutes), this is normal behaviour.

Comment: Yes, I'm doing all of those and the leak is still present. I see the handle leak in task manager, but running net stat shows that there are no close-waiting connections.
Microsoft's DebugDiag tool suggests those handles are event-handles, that's the only clue I've got.

Comment: okay, is the leak also present after destroying the accepting TcpListener object?

Comment: no, it isn't (I first thought it does, but I was mistaken). What does that tell us? After all, I can't stop the listener from time to time

Comment: i guess it only tells us that the handles are still associated and not "lost". maybe you have to provide more code. are threads or objects involved that could still have a reference to the socket?